# Tower Outta Nowhere quest breaks when I give GOG book to the wizard

Tags: the-witcher-3

Quest Tower Outta Nowhere is bugged.

I gave GOG book to the wizard in "Tower Outta Nowhere" quest in Skellige, the wizard deactivated barrier, some shining glowing orb appeared, and nothing else happens.

Reloading from earlier save doesn't help.

I'm stuck. I'm using Wither 3 version 1.0.7.

Originally I [found solution here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/594820656458454119/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what helped me: I made save **after** giving the wizard the book, and reloaded that save. After save loaded game unstuck, and I could talk to the wizard.